# What increases the size of the Magento account? What can I delete to decrease the size? I'm up to 13.62 GB on the cPanel backup

Tags: core-file-storage, local-storage

Magento 1.9.1.0
890 products

When I do a cPanel backup of my account - it comes up to be 13.62 GB. I think that it makes a backup of the Email also - the total size of the Email should be around 3 GB (2984 MB). Which would indicate the size of the Magento store to be around 10.6 GB in the tar.gz compresssed format. I deleted the Cache folder. What are other things I can delete? Is the var/report folder OK? Anything else? Would deleting any of the unnecessary folders make Magento run faster?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the biggest thing that would impact the size of your codebase is the media folder. Here, Magento stores all the images for each your products and other cms content. In the past, I've also seen developers store database backups within the code. If that's the case it could be taking up a lot of unnecessary space.

If you download and uncompress the tar.gz you can right click on each of the top level folders to see which ones are taking up the most disk space.

Deleting the unnecessary folders will have no effect on how fast Magento runs. However, it will save you some space on your server which means you won't have to upgrade your hosting as soon.

I've worked with a client in the past who had over 100 thousand products and their media folder contained over 40GB of images. There isn't and issue with this but it required us to set them up with hosting that included more disk space.

Comment: Use n98-magerun with this add on: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons/blob/master/README.md which ads commands to clean up media of orphan images.